# React Native Detox hardware limitations?

Tags: react-native, detox

I've set up detox on my 2014 mac mini, which is also running jenkins to serve as my CI.

I've been getting inconsistent test results from isNil or isVisible matcher, slow simulator boot up, and tests will always fail when running in headless mode.

I've had to set up jest timeouts as well as await timeouts on the tests to factor the slowness of my mac mini booting up a simulator.

When I run detox on my local 2018 macbook pro, I see no issues and the tests pass fine without so much delay.

Are there hardware limitations that I should be aware about or is there anyway to speed up my mac mini so it doesn't take so long to boot a device?

Is become quite a hassle the detox test is becoming more painful

Comment: One solution that I came across when I struggled with the simulator not being booted causing my tests to fail was to boot the simulator before the build process had started. That way the simulator had a chance to boot up while the node packages were installed, then the build was made, so when the tests were ready to run everything was good to go. Not the most ideal solution but it worked for me.